# How to run multiple threads on buffered data in twisted?

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, twisted

[Image of an abstract model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/capy2.png)

I have implemented this model using python-socketIO, however I am unable to do something similar in twisted. I have a feed of data coming in, I take this read this data in blocks of 8192 bytes. This is binary data, so it needs to be processed before sending it to clients. However I can't stop the input of data for processing. In python-socketIO I used to put the function to work on this data as a background task, while I continue to fetch more data. Any ideas how I can do something similar in using twisted library of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "background task" I suppose you mean a thread.  You can work with threads using Twisted.  The most approach with the fewest concepts involved is `deferToThread`:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.threads import deferToThread

class YourProtocol(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        d = deferToThread(your_process_data, data)
        d.addCallback(your_result_handler)
        d.addErrback(your_error_handler)
```